# Date Conversion for SQL

Tags: sql

How do you convert a coming date format?

Coming Date Format is 'mm/dd/yyyy - Current'

Conversion I want is 'mm/dd/yyyy - mm/dd/yyyy'

The current part needs to be converted to System date in the format of 'mm/dd/yyyy'.

Date coming in SQL and getting converted in SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Use convert function. For example:

SELECT CONVERT( CHAR( 20 ), getdate(), 103 )

103 
 dd/mm/yy[yy] 
 104 
 dd.mm.yy[yy] 
 105 
 dd-mm-yy[yy]

Answer (score 0):

There is, AFAIK, no standard way to do this. It's slightly different for each database vendor. Take a look at the date and/or string function documentation for your particular database.